# About large z behavior of hypergeometric function $_2F_1(1/2,1/2,1;z)$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

The hypergeometric function $_2F_1(\large \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1-\frac{u}{\Lambda^2}} {2} \large)$ at large  $\mid u\mid$ can be approximated by 
$$ -\frac{\Lambda}{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{2}{u}} \ln(\frac{u}{\Lambda^2})$$

How to approximate hypergeometric function at large  argument ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, it seems you already gave the answer. Are you looking for a proof then?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to get it.

Comment: The ${}_2F_1$ series has radius of convergence $1$, so to discuss values $z>1$ you must use the analytic continuation of that series.  Aren't there some Gaussian relations that write such a ${}_2F_1$ in terms of another ${}_2F_1$ with other arguments, that will help near $z=\infty$?

Comment: By the way, Maple says ${}_2F_1(1/2,1/2;1;z) = (2/\pi)K(\sqrt{z})$ in terms of complete elliptic integral $K$.

Comment: functions.wolfram.com has formulas for behavior at infinity: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/06/01/05/01/05/ But like the original question, no references or proofs are included.

Comment: Thanks. if I use mathematica software, I can find the fisr order behavior $_2F_1(1/2,1/2,1;z)$ is
$$  _2F_1(1/2,1/2,1;z) \sim \frac{(\pi - 4 i \log2 + i\log[1/z]) \sqrt{\frac{1}{z}}}{\pi}$$
But I want know something without software. Integral table, such as  Gradsbteyn & Ryzbik , is ok for me. I did not find the similiar formula.

Comment: Did you try looking at standard sources on asymptotic expansions of integrals? It's probably doable by some standard technique.

Comment: naively, expanding the integral of in $1/z$ will give factors like $1/\sqrt{z}$,$1/\sqrt{z^3}$  and integral of $x$. I can not see where the $\ln(\frac{1}{z})$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation), this case (of integer third argument to the hypergeometric function) is discussed in [Abramowitz and Stegun.](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/)

**EDIT** While the comment is correct, the answer *is* in Abramowitz and Stegun. In particular, check out equations 15.4.8 and 15.4.9. See also 15.5.16-17, and see also the transformation formulas in 15.3, which transform the point at infinity to your favorite other singular points.

Comment: It is about $z \sim 0$ in Wiki, and for discussion about $z \sim \infty$, it requires $a-b$ is a integer which is not satisfied here.

Comment: @user24304 See the edit.

Comment: @IgorRivin I'm following along and not really seeing a log in Abramowitz & Stegun. OTOH, their short section 15.7 "Asymptotic Expansions" does refer to Erdélyi et al., Higher transcendental functions, vol. 1, which says most clearly in its section 2.3.2 "Asymptotic expansions" (pp. 75-76):...

Comment: ..."The behavior of the solutions [F(a,b,c,z)] of the hypergeometric equation for large values of $|z|$ can be fully described by means of the formulas for
the analytic continuation into the neighborhood of the point at $z = \infty$.
Unless $a — b$ is an integer, every solution $u(z)$ can be put into the form
$u(z) = \lambda_1z^{-a} +\lambda_2z^{-b} + O(z^{-a-1}) + O(z^{-b-1})$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are constants; **if $a-b$ is an integer, $z^{-a}$ or $z^{-b}$ has to be multiplied by a factor $\log z$.**"

Comment: For a more modern (and freely available online) resource, see [the corresponding chapter in the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15), A&S's successor.